# Php image upload : Changing image names

Tags: php, sql, image, mysqli, image-uploading

I have an image upload form that uploads images to the database.

Here is the code I use, it generates a random value for each image, thanks to the trick below.

```
$name = "cover".rand(1,1000000).".jpg"; // generates random image name
```

But what if the uploaded file isn't a .jpg? It can be a png, gif or any other image file. How can I dynamically add the file extension to the end of the image?

I also want to use a stronger randomizer function, what kind of function should I use to give each image a unique value?

Form

```
<form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="uploadform">
    <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="350000">
    <input name="picture" type="file" id="picture" size="50">
    <input name="upload" type="submit" id="upload" value="Upload Picture!">
</form>
```

upload.php

```
<?php
// if something was posted, start the process... 
if (isset($_POST['upload'])) {

// define the posted file into variables 
    $name = $_FILES['picture']['name'];
    $tmp_name = $_FILES['picture']['tmp_name'];
    $type = $_FILES['picture']['type'];
    $size = $_FILES['picture']['size'];

// if your server has magic quotes turned off, add slashes manually 
    if (!get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
        $name = addslashes($name);
    }

// open up the file and extract the data/content from it 
    $extract = fopen($tmp_name, 'r');
    $content = fread($extract, $size);
    $content = addslashes($content);
    fclose($extract);

// connect to the database 
    include "../cn/connect.php";

   $name = "cover".rand(1,1000000).".jpg"; // generates random image name

// the query that will add this to the database 
    $stmt = $sqli->prepare("INSERT INTO image1(name, type, size) VALUES (?,?,?)");
    $stmt->bind_param("sss", $name, $_FILES['picture']['type'], $_FILES['picture']['size']);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->close();
    echo "Mission has been completed, sir!";

    if (!empty($_FILES)) {
        $target = "upload/";
        $target = $target . basename($_FILES['picture']['name']);
        $ok = 1;
        $picture_size = $_FILES['picture']['size'];
        $picture_type = $_FILES['picture']['type'];
        //This is our size condition 
        if ($picture_size > 5000000) {
            echo "Your file is too large.<br>";
            $ok = 0;
        }


        //This is our limit file type condition 
        if ($picture_type == "text/php") {
            echo "No PHP files<br>";
            $ok = 0;
        }

        //Here we check that $ok was not set to 0 by an error 
        if ($ok == 0) {
            Echo "Sorry your file was not uploaded";
        } //If everything is ok we try to upload it
        else {
            if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['picture']['tmp_name'], $target)) {
                echo "The file " . basename($_FILES['picture']['name']) . " has been uploaded <br/>";
            } else {
                echo "Sorry, there was a problem uploading your file.";
            }
        }
    }

    echo "Successfully uploaded your picture!";
} else {
    die("No uploaded file present");
}

?>
```

Comment: why not just concatenate the extension name

Comment: Could've done that. Used this one and solved the issue, now I need to randomize image names. 
$path = $_FILES['picture']['name'];
$ext = pathinfo($path, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

Comment: just concatenate it on the end of your string just like you normally would do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wont

```
$type = $_FILES['picture']['type'];
```

Tell you what type of file it is? Just use that to append the (valid) correct file format.

Comment: It gives the type but not the extension "as is". I needed to get the extension directly, not the "image/png" one. I think I could have split it with substr(), but couldn't think it when I ask this question.

Comment: You could use `if ($type == "image/png") {}` as it is unqiue, only a png file will show "image/png" and only that. Same goes for the other formats.